# css анимация звука

Tags: html, css, аудио

Хотел бы узнать вашего совета, я вроде не совсем отбитый но никак не могу понять как на эту анимацию иконки
http://nisnom.com/veb-razrabotki/krasivaya-animatsiya..
возможно наложить на кнопку стоп и кнопку воспроизведения ? 
у меня стоит авто воспроизведение музыки при входе на сайт
выглядит вот так

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay loop" type="audio/mp3" volume="1000"> <source src="BossLife.mp3"> </audio> 
<div> <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Пауза</button> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Воспроизведение</button> 
</div>
```

и все работает. 
но никак не могу установить что бы при анимации музыка ставилась на паузу а затем по нажатию опять воспроизводилась.

если кому не трудно прошу можно пример скинуть ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay loop" type="audio/mp3" volume="1000">
<source src="BossLife.mp3">
</audio>
<div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Пауза</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Воспроизведение</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Не пойму, как сей ответ отвечает на вопрос...